# Does the Virtuoso Fascinate Feature stack with the base bard fascinate?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, bard

I looked at both of them and its never clear if they stack with each other can someone add some clarity on this?

Frankly I'm not sure if it works or not I want it to I see no reason for it not to, but its so vague that it doesn't really clarify it all that way, and could make the difference whether someone stops at bard 6 or 7

Answer (score 3):

The prestige class virtuoso (*Complete Adventurer* 89-92) at level 1 gains the class feature bardic music which says, in part, that

> Virtuoso levels stack with bard levels for the purpose of determining the virtuoso’s daily uses of his bardic music abilities… and the value of
>   the bonus granted by inspire courage….
>
> A virtuoso also gains the *fascinate* bardic music ability, if he doesn’t already have it. He can use his performance to cause one or more creatures to become fascinated with him. (89-90)

Thus a virtuoso only gains *fascinate* if he doesn't already have *fascinate*; levels in virtuoso don't improve *fascinate* and only improve what the description says it improves (specifically uses per day and inspire courage). (However, this DM can't see a big, game-breaking imbalance in allowing a virtuoso to *fascinate* a couple of more folks and letting the level in bard and virtuoso stack for such a purpose.)

It's likely intended and seems reasonable that a virtuoso that newly gains *fascinate* because of his first level in virtuoso progresses his new *fascinate* ability with his virtuoso level. Although this isn't as explicit as it could be, it's how I'd rule it.